# procedure outputs automatically #t or #f in Scheme programming language

Tags: scheme

I started Learning scheme from "The Little Schemer" and I am using Dr.Racket IDE.

```
(define atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (and (not (null? x)) (not (pair? x)))))

(atom? '(a b c))

(define lat?
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((null? x) #t)
      ((atom? (car x)) (lat? (cdr x)))
      (else "It is not a lat"))))

(lat? '(a b c J))
```

This is my code to find if the given list contains only atoms or not.
whenever i give any list other than null list,
first it executes the first cond if the list is `null` since it is not null output of the `null?` is false it outputs`#f` but I dont want to see the output of the null? procedure. I just want `#f` if it is `lat?` is `false` and `#t` if `lat?` is `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `#f` you see is from `(atom? '(a b c))`. Delete or comment-out the line.

If you just want `#t` or `#f` from  `lat?`. change your `else` clause:

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((null? x) #t)
      ((atom? (car x)) (lat? (cdr x)))
      (else #f))))
```

or simply

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (x)
    (or (null? x)
        (and (atom? (car x)) (lat? (cdr x))))))
```